# Critical Points of non linear differential equation

Tags: nonlinear-system

In this system of non-linear differential equation:
$$
x' = (x-y)(x+y) \\
y' = (2+x)(5+y)
$$

I'm getting four critical points $(-2,-2)$, $(-5,-5)$, $(-2,2)$ and $(5,-5)$ instead of three as suggested by the question textbook. Can anyone check?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I also got 4 solutions for critical points